# How to define chat message background view height

Tags: android, layout

Em. I'm making chat app now .there is something confused me. I want define chat message background's view hight same as user head image . like this:
[image]

The blue picture is message background .I used TextView .As designer designed the UserHead view hight is defined as a normal value. but If I defined TextView height same as the UserHead imageView hight, another problem will come:
  if the TextMessage content was length enough it's can't show all message because of I limited the TextView width and the hight was limited by default value. so my question is how can i keep the TextView hight same as userHead imageview hight by default and when content is length enough the hight will change inorder to show all message .

Answer (score 0):

> TextView hight same as userHead imageview hight by default and when content is length enough the hight will change inorder to show all message .

Give a minHeight to the text view and set height to wrap content.  Doing this it work as per you need

```
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: thanks for u answer .I'm considering change the image resource file hight. I found even  I set minHeight but because of the resource image hight was higher then userhead img .so minheight is useless .

Comment: But changing the resource height wont work  if you have more than 1000 character in message